# Tenforflow Sparse Arithmetic

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

Hi I'm learning tensorflow right now and I am have a sparse dataset which is made up of three columns, date, bond, spread. I figured that storing this data in sparse tensor with bond as one dimension, and date as another will make operations on this tensor feel natural, do let me know if you think there is a better way.

I am trying to perform arithmetic on two slices of the tensor where I add/subtract values on one date only if given tensor values is not empty, and while I found some functions that help me with that task I can't shake off the feeling that I'm missing a really simple solution to the problem.

Using data bellow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

indicies = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 2], [2, 2]]
values   = [10    , 10    ,  10   , 11    ,  11   ]

spreads = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indicies, values, [3, 3])
```

In above example I intend to use dimension one for dates, and dimension two for bonds such that

```
tf.sparse.slice(spreads,[0,2],[3,1])
```

Gives me all spreads for date`2`, but apparently subtraction is not supported for `SparseTensor`, nor can I use `tf.math.subtract`. So I am no longer sure what is supported.

Specifically what I want to accomplish in above example is subtract date `0` for all other dates only if bond has spread on both dates. For Example bond `0` shows up in date `0` and `1` but not date `2` so I want to subtract spread in date `0` from both dates `0` and `1`.
Final tensor would look like this:

```
indicies2 = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 2]]
output    = [ 0    , 0     , 0,    ,  1    ]
tf.sparse.to_dense(tf.sparse(tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indicies2, output, [3, 3])))
```

> tf.Tensor: id=128, shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
>   array([[0, 0, 0],
>         [ 0, 0, 1],
>         [ 0, 0, 0]])

I guess easy solution would be to use `tf.sparse.to_dense` but that kind of defeats the whole point of using `SparseTensor`, so I'm not really sure if I missed something in API docs that makes my solution possible or did I got wrong completely by trying to use `SparseTensor`?
At the end of the day I am just looking to perform some math for each value of a tensor if that value has a match in another tensor.

UPDATE:
I realized that I can apply `tf.math/negative` to one of the slices to subtract two slices problem is that output assumes that if value in one slice is missing then it can be assumed to be some default value(zero).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is any simple trick to make that work that easily. I would either make the dense computation or write the sparse computation myself. That is a bit trickier, so probably only worth it if the data is really very sparse and you would save a lot memory and computation. Here is a way to do that:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

bonds = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
dates = [0, 1, 0, 2, 2]
values = [10, 10, 10, 11, 11]
# Find date 0 data
m0 = tf.equal(dates, 0)
bonds0 = tf.boolean_mask(bonds, m0)
values0 = tf.boolean_mask(values, m0)
# Find where date 0 bonds are
match = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(bonds, 1), bonds0)
# Compute the amount to subtract from each data point
values_sub = tf.reduce_sum(values0 * tf.dtypes.cast(match, values0.dtype), 1)
# Compute new spread values
values_new = values - values_sub
# Mask null values
m_valid = tf.not_equal(values_new, 0)
bonds_new = tf.boolean_mask(bonds, m_valid)
dates_new = tf.boolean_mask(dates, m_valid)
values_new = tf.boolean_mask(values_new, m_valid)
# Make sparse tensor
indices_new = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.stack([bonds_new, dates_new], 1), tf.int64)
spreads_new = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indices_new, values_new, [3, 3])
tf.print(spreads_new)
# 'SparseTensor(indices=[[1 2]
#  [2 2]], values=[1 11], shape=[3 3])'
```

For the example that you give, I get the outputs `(1, 2) => 1` and `(2, 2) => 11` - `(2, 2)` is unaffected because there was no spread for `2` in date `0`. That is different from what you wrote, so let me know if that is not what you meant.